How can we create a storybook with reusable components/function/services for usage with Expo (React-Native/ReactJS)?
I would like to build a storybook for using in an intranet environment. How can I do that?
We could use a submodule or a npm package.
Its starting to feel bad having to copy components over projects.
We cannot use external repositories like Github.
